# Password protect hosts file without encrypting it?

Tags: permissions, password, encryption

I am trying to set up parental control on my computer by putting unwanted websites in the hosts file. Now I need to secure it so that no one can open it.

Encryption is not an option, as then the system wont be able to read the hosts file...

Using root to protect it is also not an option, as the user of the computer will need admin rights...

Making another user would be OK, but i believe anyone with root access can change the file's owner.

I need a solution where the file cannot be edited without the password. I don't mind if the method of protection can be removed, since it won't be able to be restored and set up without the password.

**I was thinking some sort of script to open a dialogue that asks for the password whenever the hosts file is opened, and if it isn't given, then it will close the hosts file immediately.**

So if anyone has such an idea or can right a simple script that will do this, i would be extremely greatful!

Comment: If the user has root privileges he can change the file. However if he is not a experienced linux user you can set the file immutable by using chattr +i /etc/hosts. The user can change that back by chattr -i /etc/hosts, but maybe he does not know it. Maybe you could also block the file with selinux.

Comment: But you should never give someone root access if you do not trust him

Comment: With root access to the untrusted user you'll have to think out of the box. Perhaps just use a local DNS resolver that inhibits parental control based on name resolution. Some routers have this functionality embedded. Don't forget to also firewall use of other DNS servers (only outbound UDP+TCP port 53 is allowed to local resolver).

Answer (score 1):

Give your kids non-sudo accounts.  A non-sudo account cannot and will not be able to edit the /etc/hosts.  They will be able to see the content, but that's not really a problem is it?

Ubuntu does not use the "root account" in the strictest sense: you have a user that can get "sudo", basically temporary "root" rights.  In the lingo of the "User Account"  applet the account type is a "Administrator".  You want the account type "Standard".  Such an account cannot change system settings and it will work just fine for nearly any normal task.  (Coming from a Windows world, this is *exactly* the same by the way there.)

Basically, what you want is: create an account for each member of the family.  Set your account as "Administrator" and the rest as "Standard".  Password protect your account and... there you are.  You have what you want.

A small word on what you are actually trying to achieve.  You are blacklisting sites, which basically means "these sites are not allowed", which is thoroughly ineffective.  The only way to be sure is to "whitelist", which means "disallow everything, and allow only these sites".  Do note that this is not possible using the hosts file. 
I'm just telling you, the way you plan to do this **is** going to fail.

Comment: I am the "kid" and I need to protect the computer against myself, and my father will have the password. I need a sudo account, since i often install and uninstall software, among other sudo-requiring tasks. (I basically use sudo every day). Whatever solution I put, I know I will be able to remove it, I just need to not be able to put it back on, that way my father can just check that its not been removed.

Comment: Sorry, no...

You have a conflict of interest.  You cannot at the same time protect yourself and be the supreme ruler of the machine.  It simply is **logically impossible**.  Think about it...  root = full command of the machine and to install and remove software, you need that.

At this point, you need a solution on your network.  Basically a firewall or proxy in between your machine and the Internet, fully controlled by your father to which you have no access. 

Check your router.  It might have something like that.